# Is this code in O(n) or O(n²)? (Python Code)

Tags: python, big-o

Our Professor gave us this Code as an example for the big-O notation O(n). But I wonder why. In my opinion is this code in O(n²). I hope you can help me.

```
def g(n):
     x = n
     y = 1
     while x > 0:
          x = x - 1
          y = y + n
     while y > 0:
          y = y - 1
     return True
```

I thought a code is in O(n²), when I have a loop inside a loop. This code shows two seperate loops, so it should be O(2n), but I can ignore the constants and I got O(n). Please, correct me if I´m wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Python doesn't have integer overflow, right? So the loop is endless?

Comment: Your question is contradictory: why do you think it is O(n^2), yet then you say it should be O(2n), with an explanation. What is your reasoning then for it being O(n^2)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first loop is O(N). It runs a number of times proportional to the size of n.

The second loop runs a number of times proportional to the size of y. Since y equals n**2 at the start of the loop, that makes it O(N^2).

Since the function contains an O(N) loop and an O(N^2) loop, the function is O(N^2) in total.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of your code is *O(n^2)* because `y` will always end up being n * n from the first loop, which adds n to `y` for n times, so the second loop will iterate over n * n times.

Answer (score 0):

```
def g(n):
     x = n           # x = n
     y = 1
     while x > 0:    
          x = x - 1  # loop through x times (since x=n, n times) 
          y = y + n  # in the end, y = (1 + n) + ((1+n) + n) + (((1+n) + n) + n) ... = n + n*n
     while y > 0:    # loops n + n^2 number of times
          y = y - 1
     return True
```

As you can see, it's because the value of y ends up being n + n^2, so O(n^2) is the time complexity.

Answer (score -1):

In Python, o(n^2) would look more like this:

```
def g(n):
    x = n
    y = 1
    while x > 0:
        x = x - 1
        y = y + n
        while y > 0:
            y = y - 1
 return True
```

It's the nested loops that make it n^2, not the fact that there are two loops, and in Python nesting is indicated by indenting.

Comment: Dear Mr. -1, Since Python is far from a primary language for me, if I got my code sample wrong I'd love to know how.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you're just confused with python's indentations.

Those two loops are not **nested!**, the second loop will start only when the first loop finishes, which normally has the complexity of the **summation** of both loop

In other words, the first loop will take O(N), as `x` will reach 0 in `n` loops. The second loop will take O(N^2), as `y` will have the value of n^2 at the beginning of second loop.

Therefore, the total complexity will be O(N + N^2), and as you probably know, Big-Oh neglects minor terms, so we will end up with O(N^2).